# Community ads for other sites, 2015 edition!

Tags: discussion

Could some artistic people put together some quality community ads to put on other sites?

I'd recommend

[Sci-Fi Community Ads](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5326/community-promotion-ads-2015)
[Roleplaying Community ads](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5288/community-promotion-ads-2015)
and
[Gaming/Arqade Community Ads](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10168/community-promotion-ads-2015)

So what do people think? Can we do this?

Comment: Absolutely do advertise on RPG.SE! We'd welcome it.

Comment: I'm sure everyone agrees that _someone_ should do this ... someone else, preferably ...

Comment: @EricWilson Pitch Stone ideas and I'll see what I can come up with